# Table row on click function is not working in Angular7

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I am trying to call a function whenever i click a row in an HTML table but it is not working and it is not giving any errors.

I've tried several things, and online code shows that the way i try it, it should be working.

My code is as following:

Html:

```
<h2>Userstories</h2>

<button (click)="onNewStory()">New Story</button>

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let story of userstories" ng-click="onUpdate(story)" [class.selected]="story === selectedStory">
      <td>{{story.id}}</td>
      <td>{{story.name}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="onUpdate(story)">Click me!</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<app-userstory-detail [story]="selectedStory"></app-userstory-detail>
```

And my .ts looks like this:

```
  selectedStory: UserStory;
  onNewStory() {
    var newStory = {id:this.userstories[this.userstories.length-1].id+1, name:"", description:"Deze is nieuw", status:"open", owner:USERS[1]};
    this.userstories.push(newStory);
    this.selectedStory = newStory;
  }

  onUpdate(userstory: UserStory): void {
    this.selectedStory = userstory;
    console.log(this.selectedStory);
  }
```

Currently my console is not printing the log, when i try to call the onUpdate method. The expected result is to see some output in the logs, but i have no clue why it is not firing the onUpdate method.

Comment: Replace `ng-click` with `(click)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In angular 7 you can use `(click)` which is similar to `ng-click` of Angular JS.

Try:

```
<h2>Userstories</h2>

<button (click)="onNewStory()">New Story</button>

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let story of userstories" (click)="onUpdate(story)" [class.selected]="story === selectedStory">
      <td>{{story.id}}</td>
      <td>{{story.name}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="onUpdate(story)">Click me!</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<app-userstory-detail [story]="selectedStory"></app-userstory-detail>
```

[`StackBlitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwwlnf)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` is actually for AngularJS (1.x)

You want to use `(click)` which is for Angular.

DOCUMENTATION: https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-click

Answer (score 1):

The event is fired twice. In `<tr>` and in `<button>`.
Try this:

```
<h2>Userstories</h2>

<button (click)="onNewStory()">New Story</button>

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let story of userstories" [class.selected]="story === selectedStory">
      <td>{{story.id}}</td>
      <td>{{story.name}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="onUpdate(story)">Click me!</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<app-userstory-detail [story]="selectedStory"></app-userstory-detail>
```